# Here i want to pass each json object to another activity and set that object value to some textview

Tags: json

### pass the vehiclename object to another activity

and set that value as a text view

### Please Help Me

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object1 = response.getJSONObject("liveMapResponseVO");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = object1.getJSONArray("locations");
                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("vehicleName"));
                            movie.setRating(jsonObject.getString("speed"));
                            movie.setGenre(jsonObject.getString("stopTime"));
                            movie.setYear(jsonObject.getString("idleTime"));
                            Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.getString("vehicleName"));
                            movieList.add(movie);
                        }
                        pDialog.hide();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```